# TurtleBot navigation package

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(1) When I follow the tutorial to use the 2D Nav Goal in Rviz for TurtleBot, what navigation package is running (e.g. amcl_demo or move_base or what)?

(2) What is the most advanced autonomous navigation package for TurtleBot (e.g. avoid obstacles like PR2)?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57702/turtlebot-navigation-package/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you are following the [Navigate In A Known Map](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) tutorial.

If you look inside the launch file you start up, you'll quickly find that you are using components of the navigation stack, namely amcl for localization and move_base to control the movement and do obstacle avoidance. This is about as advanced as it gets.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1